# ¿Alguna Función para escanear una Red Local y mostrarla en Listview?

Tags: c#

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa para escanear la Red local, soy nueva trabajando código en C# y necesito hacer una función que pe permita hacer un escaneo de todas las ip de la Red Local y mostrarla en un listview. ¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Hola reivsa este enlace (https://fasoftwaredev.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/obtener-equipos-de-la-red-local-con-c-net/)

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO no me funciono, no sale ningun resultado en el Listview pero muchas gracias por tu tiempo